# Performance view on Java batch processing of DB result or Add serach criteria in DB itself

Tags: java, sql-server, multithreading

MsSql - 2014
Java 8

I have table which has around trillions rows.

I need to create Tool, which can process (Search tool) on this table and return data based on someDuplicateColumns.

```
 eg : column1 , column2 .
Query : Select * from Table Where ColumnName = column1 And ColumnName = column2
```

So I am confused between two approach :

1) Lets get all data based on column1 and column2 in batch of 1000 , and then do process and again and again in Batch in Multi threading. Till data Finished.

```
eg: Batch 1
Select * from Table Where rawCount from 1 to 1000
Batch 2
Similarly, Select * from Table Where rawCount from 1001 to 2000
Etc..
```

2) I will run simple query and return result based on someDuplicateColumns in Java code and let DB handle logic to return me efficiently.

```
Eg:
Select * from Table Where ColumnName = column1 And ColumnName = column2
```

I choose second one (2), and worked but its too slow. So I have added index on  two columns and it improved the performance.

My question is :

```
1) Which approach is better and How ?
2) does it right idea to add index on all search columns ?  Lets say If I have 20 search columns in my Table. So I need to add index on those?
```

Adding table script;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApiConsumerHistory]( [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [apiId] [int] NOT NULL, [apiPIds] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, [mediumType] [varchar](30) NOT NULL, [startTime] [datetime] NOT NULL, [endTime] [datetime] NOT NULL, [count] [int] NOT NULL, [successCount] [int] NOT NULL, [failCount] [int] NOT NULL, [fileSize] [varchar](20) NULL, [detectedFiles] [varchar](max) NULL, [request] [varchar](max) NULL, [response] [varchar](max) NULL, [isDeduplicate] [bit] NULL, [Exception] [text] NULL [badapiRejectReason] [text] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__apiCons__3213E83F7B113988] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
)
```

Comment: Voted to close as too broad

Comment: @Drew : Sorry, was not able to write in short.

Comment: You are writing a tool for processing batches. How you go about that with a trillion rows and what "processing" means to you is rather vague to us. Also, Microsoft has a server called 2014 but you removed that tag and left `mysql`

Comment: No, I am writing tool to search on this table through UI input.

Comment: so then paginate, in select stmt, `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count ...` , make sure your indexing is set up. On trickier joins, make sure that also, by looking at the output from `explain` (explain manual page [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) )

Comment: So, in any case, when you write a tool, as you say, only you know what you are doing, and all we can do is talk broad statements. Mainly because you say in your question "Lets say If I have 20 search columns in my Table." and then ask about indexing. We have no idea if your queries join, and if so, on what. Your schema, some other schema, your next customer's schema for your *tool*. Generically, your tool works against everything, no? So the question is way Too Broad / Unclear.

Comment: @Drew : No other schema. Only this. And question shall we do Batch processing on Java using multi threading. Or we can go ahead directly query to the table.

And if we need to create index, does it make sense to create index on every search criteria.

Comment: Ok, you aren't even showing a schema. Then you say at the very end about something like "what about my 20 columns." So, if I were you, I would show a schema of the relevant table(s). All of them. Even just one. So do a better job of documenting your question so it is not confusing. Document the question with the output of `show create table xyz` for every table xyz

Comment: @Drew : I did not get why do you need to look on the table. But I will edit my question.

Comment: So now someone can look at your columns and help with a covering index or some other strategy.